# Az function chaining with unsuccessful Fan-out/fan-in run on the first step

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I wonder how can I make `Function2` run if one the `Function1` fails in [Fan-out/fan-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-cloud-backup?tabs=csharp) scenario:

```
    var tasks = new Task<long>[files.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        // if one of the function fails with Exception, 
        // orchestrator execution does not pass  Task.WhenAll(tasks) point, but I want it to. 
    
        tasks[i] = backupContext.CallActivityAsync<long>(
            "Function1", files[i]);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    // how to reach this point if one of the task throws exception?
    await context.CallActivityAsync("Function2", null);
```

In other words, I want to wait all `Function1` to get completed, whether it's success or not, and then run `Function2`.

If I wrap `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` in the `try{} catch{}` block it does not catch the exception if one of the task is successful and runs long enough (longer than task throwing exception), ran many experiments upon it.

**UPDATE**

If I wrap tasks execution in try{} catch{}

```
try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

and `Function1` looks like this

```
        public async Task RunSubOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            if (context.GetInput<string>() == "instanceToFail")
            {
                throw new Exception("TestException");
            }

            // this is what instanceToSucced executes
            int delayInSec = 0;
            await Task.Delay(delayInSec * 1000);
        }
```

catch block hits, but once I set `int delayInSec = 180` it never hits, tried it many times. If successful instance overlives failed one, exception is not thrown in the orchestrator. I run Azure Functions 3

Comment: A `try/catch` block should do what you want. Please provide an example of how you tried to use it and the results you received.

Comment: question updated, please see code sample

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder how can I make `Function2` run if one the `Function1` fails

You can deal with the error handling in your activity function and if it fails you can handle the error and return the response accordingly to run another activity function in your orchestration.

#### Handling Error in Activity Function

```cs
 public static async Task<int> FunctionListResult([ActivityTrigger] int value, ILogger log)
 {
    try
    {
        var myOutputData = await DoSomething(value);
        return new 
        {
            int delayInsec = 0;
            return await Task.FromResult(delayInsec * 1000);
        }
     }Catch(Exception Ex)
     {
          // Handle the exception ...
            Dosomething();
            return new 
            {
                Success = false,
                ErrorMessage = Ex.Message
            };
     }
```

If an activity function fails with the respective values, you can call the other activity with that information. For better handling error you can handle the error meaningfully in activity function and return the value accordingly for your orchestration.

#### Handling in orchestration

```cs
public static async Task Run([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    try
    {
        var details = ctx.GetInput<value>();
        await context.CallActivityAsync("FunctionListResult", value);
    }
    catch (FunctionFailedException)
    {
        var otherDetails = GetOtherInput(< some value >);
        await context.CallActivityAsync("FunctionListResult", somevalue);
    }
}
```

Whenever we were not handling the error, the exceptions are logged, and instance completes with a failed status.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, but we also use AF retry mechanism, setting amount of retries and pause taken between them, I'm not sure how we keep using it in the design proposed

Comment: Even though you are using retry mechanism try to handle them accordingly. Create a new thread with the detailed information.

Comment: not sure what you meant by handle them accordingly. We need retry mechanism in place that Azure Function offers out of the box. It works based on exception AF runtime catches. If we swallow any exception, like your design demonstrates, AF retry mechanism won't work. Not sure how can we circumvent that.